# SQL: Combine value into one result when NULL or empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that returns two columns - "Title" and "Count".  When "Title" is NULL or empty (''), I want to combine the result into one row.  How can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  [Title] WHEN '' THEN 'blank' ELSE ISNULL([Title],'blank') AS [Title],
        COUNT([value]) AS [Count]
FROM ....
WHERE ....
GROUP BY [Title],[Count]
```

but because of the Group By, they are split into two different rows:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COALESCE([Title],'') = '' THEN 'blank' 
             ELSE [Title] 
        END AS [Title],
        COUNT([value]) AS [Count]
FROM ....
WHERE ....
GROUP BY CASE WHEN COALESCE([Title],'') = '' THEN 'blank' 
              ELSE [Title] 
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to Joe Stefanelli's solution:

```
Select Case
        When Len( [Title] ) > 0 Then [Title]
        Else 'blank'
        End
From ...
Group By Case
            When Len( [Title] ) > 0 Then [Title]
            Else 'blank'
            End
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the [Count] column in the GROUP BY clause seems suspicious... does it work if you only group by [Title]?

Answer (score 0):

**COALESCE**

select title_id,count(*),COALESCE(type,pub_id)
from titles
group by 
title_id,type,pub_id